# Inputting Scores to get a Grade in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following program works, but when the result is given out, it is followed up with "None." How do I remove that effect? Thanks.

```
def grades(score):
if score > 1.0:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")
elif score >= 0.9:
    print("The score is: A.")
elif score >= 0.8:
    print("The score is: B.")
elif score >= 0.7:
    print("The score is: C.")
elif score >= 0.6:
    print("The score is: D.")
elif score >= 0:
    print("The score is: F.")
else:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")

try:
    score1 = float(input("Enter Score: "))
    x = grades(score1)
    print(x)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")
```

Comment: you need to return something, otherwise you get a "None" (Add a return statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grades is a function that does not return anything
so when you write

```
x = grades(score1)
```

x does not get any value set

since the grade function does not return anything

```
so, print(x) prints None
```

remove

```
 x = grades(score1)
 print(x)
```

and replace it with

```
 grades(score1)
```

and you won't get None

or if you want to store the value of the grade and then print it
change the grades function to

```
def grades(score):
if score > 1.0:
    return "Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0."
elif score >= 0.9:
    return "The score is: A."
elif score >= 0.8:
    return "The score is: B."
elif score >= 0.7:
    return "The score is: C."
elif score >= 0.6:
    return "The score is: D."
elif score >= 0:
    return "The score is: F."
else:
    return "Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0."
elif score >= 0:
    return "The score is: F."
else:
    return "Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0."
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't `print(x)` at the end. `x` is the return value of the `grades` function, and since you never use `return`, the default value is `None`. So just do

```
try:
    score1 = float(input("Enter Score: "))
    grades(score1)
except:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from function. Instead of using print ,use return and use the same code. It will not print none .Otherwise you can remove print(x). Below should work

```
def grades(score):
        if score > 1.0:
            print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")
        elif score >= 0.9:
            print("The score is: A.")
        elif score >= 0.8:
            print("The score is: B.")
        elif score >= 0.7:
            print("The score is: C.")
        elif score >= 0.6:
            print("The score is: D.")
        elif score >= 0:
            print("The score is: F.")
        else:
            print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")

try:
    score1 = float(input("Enter Score: "))
    x = grades(score1)
    #print(x)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input between 0 and 1.0.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not return anything from `grades()`, so `x` is `None`